# Como hacer una validación para enviar un correo al ultimo id de un registro

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Cordial saludo, a todos los que me contesten y me puedan ayudar.

este es mi primer post y lo que estoy buscando es realizar una validación para enviar un correo al ultimo id de un registro.

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | correo1 |
| 124 | correo2 |

lo que tengo hasta el momento es consultar por id, los correos que tenga ese usuario, cada vez que hagan un registro, mi consulta siempre trae el ultimo id y ejecuta el envio del correo, esta consulta la estoy haciendo cada 5 minutos si encuentra uno diferente se envia el correo, si el id no cambia, no se lo envia. valga la redundancia.

Espero que entiendan y me colaboren, muchas gracias

este es mi codigo

```
`<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['usuario'] == "") {
   header("location:../index.php");
}
include("../controller/resultadosFormularioController.php");

//Add Imports and required files          

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$result = ResultadosFormularioModel::consultarMaxIdAgenda();

foreach ($result as $value) {    
   $miIdAgenda = $value['id'];
}

$idUsuario = ResultadosFormularioModel::consultarIdUsuario($miIdAgenda);

foreach ($idUsuario as $usuario) {

   $idUser = $usuario['id_usuario'];
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($idUser);
   echo '</pre>';
}

$arraySeparado = explode(",", $idUser);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arraySeparado);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($arraySeparado as $superArray) {

   $idServicios = $superArray;
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($idServicios);
   echo '</pre>';

   if (isset($idServicios)) {

      $miCorreo = ResultadosFormularioModel::consultarIdUIsuario($idServicios);

      foreach ($miCorreo as $correo) {

         $email = $correo['correo_usuario'];
      }

      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($email);
      echo '</pre>';
   }

   $idAgendaMenosUno = $miIdAgenda - 1;
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($idAgendaMenosUno);
   echo '</pre>';
}

if ($miIdAgenda > $idAgendaMenosUno) {
   // code...
   try {
      //Configure server settings
      
      $mail->send();
      echo 'Se envio el correo correctamente';
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error al enviar el mensaje. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
   }
} else {
   echo ' no se envia';
}
```

// }`

es algo ilógico porque siempre se va a cumplir

Comment: de echo si lo uso, lo que no logro hacer es que se envie una sola vez el correo. ya que las hago cada 5 minutos si el id maximo es el mismo no deberia enviar mas correo hasta que llegue uno nuevo

Comment: Agrega un campo de control en la tabla y una vez enviado el email, actualizas el registro a través del **id**, insertando un dato en el campo de control, _puede ser un valor numérico_. Así puedes buscar 5 minutos mas tarde el `MAX(id)` y si el campo de control es nulo, envías el email, pero si contiene el dato de control, no lo envías. Comenta si no soy claro con el planteamiento.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias. si lo hice de esa manera, ahora pasa que tengo varios correos y se van dos veces